# How to avoid wasting huge amounts of memory when processing DPDK mbufs?

Tags: dpdk

DPDK: 22.03
PMD: Amazon ENA

We have a DPDK application that only calls `rte_eth_rx_burst()` (we do not transmit packets) and it must process the payload very quickly. **The payload of a single network packet MUST be in contiguous memory.**

The DPDK API is optimized around having memory pools of **fixed-size** mbufs in memory pools. If a packet is received on the DPDK port that is larger than the mbuf size, but smaller than the max MTU then it will be segmented according to the figure below:

[image]

This leads us the following problems:

- If we configure the memory pool to store large packets (for example
  max MTU size) then we will always store the payload in contiguous memory, but we will waste huge amounts memory in the case we
  receive traffic containing small packets. Imagine that our mbuf size
  is 9216 bytes, but we are receiving mostly packets of size 100-300
  bytes. We are wasting memory by a factor of 90!
- If we reduce the size of mbufs, to let's say 512 bytes, then we need
  special handling of those segments in order to store the payload in
  contiguous memory. Special handling and copying hurts our performance, so it should be limited.

My final question:

1. What strategy is recommended for a DPDK application that needs to process the payload of network packets in contiguous memory? With **both** small (100-300 bytes) and large (9216) packets, without wasting huge amounts of memory with 9K-sized mbuf pools? Is copying segmented jumbo frames into a larger mbuf the only option?

Comment: let me rephrase what you are asking (please correct my understanding if it is wrong). the use case scenario you are exploring requires to use various mbuf sizes, hence the question is  `how to use DPDK mempool for smaller packets (up to 512B) with mbuf size as 640B and for larger size packets (up to 9KB) with Mbuf size as 10240B?`. If yes, can you please share DPDK version and Physical NIC details?

Comment: We are looking for a strategy to process mbufs without wasting too much memory. If we configure a large mbuf size, then we will waste a lot of memory when small packets arrive on the NIC, since mbuf size is fixed. If we configure small mbuf size, then we do not waste much memory for small packets which is good. But then we still need to support large packets. So we need a method to reassemble the segmented mbufs into one big mbuf, since we can only process payload if it is contiguous. However this hurts performance. That is all. If you need more clarification feel free to ask

Comment: Ok, thanks for information. But still details like DPDK version, Physical Nic are missing. These are essential in determining if one can leverage RTE_FLOW and per queue mempool. So please update.

Comment: DPDK version 22.03, using [Amazon's ena PMD](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/tree/main/drivers/net/ena). The NIC is Amazon's [Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)](https://pastebin.com/XXVVBngR) used in their EC2 instance technology. Click the link for a paste of the lspci -vv output.

Comment: thanksl @silversteel I will cross-check if Amazon ENA support RTE_FLOW for packet size or raw fields and suggest if we can use multiple mempool for the same NIC over the answer soon.

Comment: Hi @VipinVarghese. I am sure you are quite busy, but have you managed to find the information on the AWS ENA? Thanks again for you time

Comment: yes I got a chance I was exploring what can be done with RTE_FLOW. I will update soon too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways involving the use of HW and SW logic to make use of multiple-size mempool.

via hardware:

1. If the NIC PMD supports packet or metadata (RX descriptor) parsing, one can use RTE_FLOW `RAW` to program the flow direction to a specific queue. Where each can be set up with desired `rte_mempool`.
2. IF the NIC PMD does not support parsing of metadata (RX descriptors) but the user is aware of specific protocol fields like `ETH + MPLS|VLAN` or `ETH + IP + UDP` or `ETH + IP + UDP + Tunnel (Geneve|VxLAN)`; one can use RTE_FLOW to distribute the traffic over specific queues (`which has larger mempool object size`). thus making default traffic to fall on queue-0 (`which has smaller mempool object size`)
3. if hardware option of `flow bifurcate` is available, one can set the RTE_FLOW with `raw or tunnel` headers to be redirect to `VF`. thus `PF can make use of smaller object mempool` and `VF can make use of larger size mempool`.

via software: (if HW supported is absent or limited)

1. Using RX callback (`rte_rx_callback_fn`), one can check `mbuf->nb_segs > 1` to confirm multiple segments are present and then use ***mbuf_alloc from larger mempool, attach as first segment and then invoke rte_pktmbuf_linearize to move the content to first buffer***.
2. Pre set all queue with large size mempool object, using RX callback check `mbuf->pktlen < [threshold size]`, if yes ***alloc mbuf from smaller pool size, memcpy the content (pkt data and necessary metadata) and then swap the original mbuf with new mbuf and free the original mbuf***.

Pros and Cons:

- SW-1: this costly process, as multiple segment access memory is non-contiguous and will be done for larger size payload such as 2K to 9K. hardware NIC also has to support RX scatter or multi-segment too.
- SW-2: this is less expensive than SW-1. As there is no multiple segments, the cost can be amortized with `mtod and prefetch of payload`.

note: in both cases, the cost of `mbuf_free` within RX-callback can be reduced by maintaining a list of original mbufs to free.

Alternative option-1 (involves modifying the PMD):

- modify the PMD code `probe or create` to allocate mempool for large and small objects.
- set MAX elements per RX burst as `1 element`
- use scalar code path only
- Change `recv` function to

1. check the packet size from RX descriptor
2. comment the original code to replenish per threshold
3. check the packet size via reading packet descriptor.
4. alloc for either a large or small size mempool object.

[edit-1] based on the comment update DPDK version is `22.03` and PMD is `Amazon ENA`. Based on [DPDK NIC summary](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/overview.html) and [ENA PMD](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/ena.html) it points to

1. No RTE_FLOW RSS to specific queues.
2. No RTE_FLOW_RAW for packet size.
3. In [file](https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk/tree/drivers/net/ena/ena_ethdev.c) in function `ena_rx_queue_setup`; it supports individual `rte_mempool`

Hence current options are

1. Modify the ENA PMD to reflect support for multiple mempool size
2. Use SW-2 for rx_callback to copy smaller payload to new mbuf and swap out.

Note: There is an alternate approach by

1. creating an empty pool with external mempool
2. Use modified ENA PMD to get pool objects as single small buffers or multiple continuous pool objects.

Recommendation: Use a PMD or Programmable NIC which can bifurcate based on Packet size and then RTE_FLOW to a specific queue. To allow multiple CPU to process multiple flow setup Q-0 as default small packets, and other queues with RTE_FLOW_RSS with specific mempool.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. [Amazon lists the types of Receive Side Scaling (RSS) they support here](https://github.com/amzn/amzn-drivers/tree/master/userspace/dpdk#11-rss-support). I think none of them really help us in our case, correct?

Comment: @silversteel thanks for checking out, the RSS needed redirecting the desired packet to specific queues. Example; lets say you have 5 RX queues, in which queue-1 to queue-2 is configured for specific RTE_FLOW via RSS and queue-0 for all other smaller packets. This feature is not available in AMAZON ENA PMD. So all options of HW offload is not going to help. RX-callback (SW-2) or modifying the PMD are the only options.